# Connecting DB request to API - Android

Tags: android, database, api

I would like to do something, I don't know how to do it. But before, let me explain the previous steps:

1st: I have defined a content manager that, when I introduce a specific "**id**" from a resource, it finds such reosurce and shows it to me. In addition, I have created a POJO for the resource and an interface in which I specifiy my request.

2nd: Now I want to be able to incorporate such resources into a local data base. So, I have defined my entity for such data base (and that entity has the same attributes that the resource (consulted) from the API). Then I have defined the contract for such entity and the repository for that entity (where I have defined my query as "WHERE field "**name**" = (...)" .

3rd: After that, I have defined a ContentProvider for my DB.

4th: Finally, there is my MainActivity, which acts as a Client to consult my DB through my content provider.

Now, my question is, **how** and **where** I have to define the next:
a) When I make a search -based on the attribute name of the resource-, if the content provider doesn't find it in my local DB, then a request is made to the API (and the name specified on my search should fit with the attribute "name" 
of the resource in the API). 
b)Once the response with the resource is given, my local DB should add that resource as a new entity.

Thanks.
I hope I have explained myself well.

Comment: "I would like to do something, I don't know how to do it. " --> I encourage you to do more research before jumping on here for answers.

Comment: In fact, I have done research, but for this I have not found answer.